# How does Ruby modules lookup path behave?

Tags: ruby

```
module A
  def go
    p 'go'
  end
end

module B
  extend self
  include A
  def start
    go
  end
end

# doesn't work
# B.start

module C
  include A
  extend self
  def start
    go
  end
end

# works
C.start

module Constants
  HELLO = "Hello!"
end

module D
  extend self
  include Constants
  def start
    p HELLO
  end
end

# works
D.start
```

Could someone please explain this to me? How come `C.start` works if I `include A` first before `extend self`? How come the order works if I'm only including `Constants`?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why `D.start` work?

Because `extend self` adds method `start` to the singleton class of `D`. Look the below 2 examples:

## without `extend self`

```
module Constants
  HELLO = "Hello!"
end

module D
  #extend self
  include Constants
  def start
    p HELLO
  end
end

D.singleton_methods # => []
```

## with `extend self`

```
module Constants
  HELLO = "Hello!"
end

module D
  extend self
  include Constants
  def start
    p HELLO
  end
end

D.singleton_methods # => [:start]
```

> why B.start doesn't work ?

This is because you first added the methods of module `B` to its singleton methods, then included the methods of module `A`, so `#go` is not added to the singleton methods of `B`. Take a look at the below 2 examples.

## first `include A` then `extend self`.

`B.start` will work here because, you first included methods from `A` to `B`. Then adding all the methods(methods which are defined in `B` and included from `A`) of `B` to the singleton class of `B`. Thus call to `#go` is succeed within `B.start`.

```
module A
  def go
    p 'go'
  end
end

module B
  include A
  extend self
  def start
    go
  end
end

B.singleton_methods # => [:start, :go]
```

## first `extend self`, then `include A`.

`B.start` will not work here because, you first extended methods from `A` to `B`, then only all the methods from `B` has been added to the singleton class of `B`. After that you included methods from `A`, this is the reason `#go` not added to the singleton class of `B`. Thus call to `#go` is not succeed within `B.start`.

```
module A
  def go
    p 'go'
  end
end

module B
  extend self
  include A
  def start
    go
  end
end

B.singleton_methods # => [:start]
```

I hope why `C.start` works is now understood.